# Javascript slice method testing issue

Tags: javascript

another Javascript newbie question here. Suppose I get an alert if there isn't any space in the input string. but I don't get any alert at all. I got this code block from a book and trying to learn by doing in jsfiddle. Am I missing something here? thank you!

```
var str = prompt("enter some text");
var numChars = str.length;
for (var i = 0; i < numChars; i++){
    if (str.slice(i, i + 2 ) === " ") {
        alert("no double spaces");
        break;
    }        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ruW2/

Comment: You should compare against double spaces `"  "`, not single space.

Comment: In addition to what thefourtheye said, your code looks to be checking *for* the existence of a double space, not checking for the absence of it.

Comment: it's not doing anything even with the "  ".

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/5ruW2/1/ and enter a string that has to consecutive spaces and you'll get the alert.

Comment: j08691 do you get an alert? I don't get anything though..

Comment: I sure do. Are you entering two consecutive spaces? Try `dfsd  fdesfsd`

Comment: oh i got it. thanks for your kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the if statement to check for double spaces, with two spaces between the quotes, and change the alert to read "Double Spaces!" it works.

```
var str = prompt("enter some text");
var numChars = str.length;

for (i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
   if (str.slice(i, i + 2) === "  ") {
    alert("Double Spaces!");

   }
}
```